# Why my source code coverage result looks so wierd

Tags: c++, gcc, gcov

I'm trying to find out the coverage of my source code by GCOV. And follow is a part of the result:

```
     328                 :          8 : char* GetNumber() {
 329 [ +  - ][ +  - ]:          8 :     Log(__FILE__, __LINE__, CLASS_NAME, "Enter GetAccountNumber", "");
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
             [ +  - ]
 330 [ +  - ][ +  - ]:          8 :     Log(__FILE__, __LINE__, CLASS_NAME, "Leave GetAccountNumber", "");
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
             [ +  - ]
 331         [ +  - ]:          8 :     return this->Number.c_str();
 332                 :            : }
```

I did'n use the option -coverage, and as default, coverage option is enable.
I wonder why branch data looks so wierd. The GCOV document said:

```
               ’ + ’: Branch was taken at least once
               ’ - ’: Branch was not taken
               ’ # ’: The basic block containing the branch was never executed
```

so why there 4 +/- in every line, and even in the line there are no "line".

Comment: Is `Log` perhaps a macro that expands to several lines?

Comment: What about the 4 times +/- ?